# Keep relation between nested http calls to JSON-API with Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, json-api

**Problem:** I'm using RXJS in an Angular 2 project. I get data from a JSON-API. The API delivers studies and questionnaires. In our model a study can "contain" one or more questionnaires. Studies have IDs and questionnaires have IDs. I want to list all questionnaires with their associated study's ID but I'm losing the "link" between study ID and  and questionnaire object.

**Example:** Lets say Questionnaire IDs 4,5,6 are associated to study ID 1 and questionnaire IDs 7, 8 are associated to study ID 2.

The studies looks like this (GET: `.../api/v1/studies/1`):

```
{type: "study", id: "1", attributes: Object}
{type: "study", id: "2", attributes: Object}
```

The questionnaires looks like this (e.g.: GET: `.../api/v1/questionnaires/4`):

```
{type: "questionnaires", id: "4", attributes: Object}
{type: "questionnaires", id: "5", attributes: Object}
{type: "questionnaires", id: "6", attributes: Object}
{type: "questionnaires", id: "7", attributes: Object}
{type: "questionnaires", id: "8", attributes: Object}
```

I want to display all questionnaires in one list and for each questionnaire and show the study ID it's associated to like this:

```
{type: "questionnaires", id: "4", attributes: Object, associatedStudyId: "1"}
{type: "questionnaires", id: "5", attributes: Object, associatedStudyId: "1"}
{type: "questionnaires", id: "6", attributes: Object, associatedStudyId: "1"}
{type: "questionnaires", id: "7", attributes: Object, associatedStudyId: "2"}
{type: "questionnaires", id: "8", attributes: Object, associatedStudyId: "2"}
```

A GET call to `.../api/v1/studies/1/questionnaires` returns:

```
[{"type": "questionnaires", "id": "4"},{"type": "questionnaires","id": "5"}]
```

**Code:** I've got that far that I have all the components I need, I just can't figure out how to attach the study ID to the according questionnaire object.

```
getQuestionnaires(studyIds) {
console.log(studyIds); // see output [1]
this.editableQuestionnaires = [];

let studyIdsObs = Rx.Observable.from(studyIds);

let questShortStream = studyIdsObs.flatMap((id) => {
  return this.apiService.getQuestionnairesOfStudy(id)
});

questShortStream.subscribe(console.log);

let questsAndStudyId = Rx.Observable.zip(studyIdsObs, questShortStream,
  (id, quests) => {
    return {
      studyId: id,
      questionnaires: quests
    }
  })

questsAndStudyId.subscribe(console.log) // see output [2]

let studyIdAndQuestIds = questsAndStudyId.map((obj) => {
  let questIds = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.questionnaires.length; i++) {
    questIds.push(obj.questionnaires[i].id);
  }
  return {
    studyId: obj.studyId,
    questionnaireIds: questIds
  }
});

studyIdAndQuestIds.subscribe(console.log); // see output [3]

let questionnaireIdsObs = studyIdAndQuestIds.flatMap(obj => {
  return Rx.Observable.from(obj.questionnaireIds);
})

questionnaireIdsObs.subscribe(console.log) // see output[4]

let questionnairesObs = questionnaireIdsObs.flatMap(id => this.apiService.getEditableQuestionnaire(id))

questionnairesObs.subscribe(console.log) // see output [5]
```

}

**Outputs:**

[1]

```
[ "1", "2", "3" ]
```

[2]

```
[ Object, Object ]
[ Object, Object, Object ]
```

[3]

```
Object { studyId: "1", questionnaires: Array[3] }
Object { studyId: "2", questionnaires: Array[2] }
```

[4]

```
4
5
6
7
8
```

[5]

```
Object { type: "questionnaires", id: "4", attributes: Object}
Object { type: "questionnaires", id: "5", attributes: Object}   
Object { type: "questionnaires", id: "6", attributes: Object}
Object { type: "questionnaires", id: "7", attributes: Object}
Object { type: "questionnaires", id: "8", attributes: Object}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do something like...

```
studyIds.forkJoin(
  studyIds.map(studyId => 
    service.getQuestionaires(studyId).map(questionaires => 
      questionaires.map(questionaire => {
        questionaire.associatedStudyId = studyId;
        return questionaire;
      })
    )
  )
);
```